# unrecognized selector sent to instance in Array

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, nsmutablearray

I am trying to add an object to an array but it senting zig bart error
"unrecognized selector sent to instance"
Below is my code

```
AppDelegate     *appdelegate              = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    NSDictionary *infomation = [self dictionaryWithContentsOfJSONString:@"Contacts.json"];
    IstructContactsOrgByEntity *ObjIstructContactsOrgByEntity=[[IstructContactsOrgByEntity alloc]initWithIstructContactsOrgByEntity:infomation];
    NSArray *array=[infomation objectForKey:@"contacts_list"];
    for (int ndx = 0; ndx < [array count]; ndx++)
    {
        NSDictionary *stream = (NSDictionary *)[array objectAtIndex:ndx];
        IstructContacts_List *ObjIstructContacts_List=[[IstructContacts_List alloc]initWithIstructContacts_List:stream];
        NSArray *Qnarray=[stream objectForKey:@"contacts"];
        for (int i=0; i<Qnarray.count; i++)
        {
            NSDictionary *Qnstream = (NSDictionary *)[Qnarray objectAtIndex:i];
            IstructContacts *ObjIstructContacts=[[IstructContacts alloc]initWithIstructContacts:Qnstream];
            [ObjIstructContacts_List.m_muteArrContacts addObject:ObjIstructContacts];
        }

        [ObjIstructContactsOrgByEntity.m_muteArrContacts_List addObject:ObjIstructContacts_List];

    }
    [appdelegate.m_ArrContactsOrgEntity addObject:ObjIstructContactsOrgByEntity];
```

The last line  `[appdelegate.m_ArrContactsOrgEntity addObject:ObjIstructContactsOrgByEntity];`
is causing me the problem.

Comment: How many questions about *unrecognised selector* and *JSON* are there I wonder?  I bet I could find 5 dupes in 2 minutes.

Comment: What is zig bart error?? Did you mean **SIGABRT**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that the compiler thinks you've declared "`m_ArrContactsOrgEntity`" as something other than a NSMutableArray.

Otherwise, you wouldn't be seeing that "unrecognized selector" error.

Another hint of advice for you, best practice in Objective-C is that variables should always start with lower case letters.  Change "`ObjIstructContacts`", "`Qnarray`" and "`Qnstream`" to start with lower case letters.

Answer (score 0):

```
**AppDelegate.h**

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *m_ArrContactsOrgEntity;


@synthesize m_ArrContactsOrgEntity;

**AppDelegate.m**

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   self.m_ArrContactsOrgEntity = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

and then addObject using AppDelegate Object.

Thanks.

Comment: Whilst this does seem correct I have few recommendation just to improve slightly. This assumes that the developer is not using `ARC` you should include this in your answer and possibly even give the `ARC` version which is just change the `retain` to `strong` and remove the `autorelease` and it is recommended (Not required) that `@synthesize` should be done like `@synthesize m_ArrContactsOrgEntity = _m_ArrContactsOrgEntity;`.

Comment: I would also recommend explaining what your code does in your answer, just because if a new developer comes along looking for an answer they aren't going to know what is here. Code on its own without an explanation is normally pretty bad but with an explanation can improve the answer a lot. Only recommendations to help improve your answer you could just ignore them if you like.

Answer (score 0):

```
m_ArrContactsOrgEntity must be NSmutableArray instead of NSArray.

NOW, You will add any items in m_ArrContactsOrgEntity array.
```